Passing "shopify_access_token" in the header of my request to API endpoint from Shopify web app
I have an embedded Shopify app that my store uses. The app is just the front end and I have a few Azure Function App to host my different APIs for the app.
In these function app I have a helper file which will take headers from the request and verify the Shopify token. This is to restrict the endpoints from being called from anywhere other than the Shopify app.
authentication_helper.py
import os
import requests
import json

from azure.functions import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from shared.log_helper import logger

INTERNAL_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('INTERNAL_SECRET')

def verify_shopify_token(domain: str, token: str) -> bool:
    try:
        response = requests.get(f'https://{domain}/admin/shop.json', headers={'X-Shopify-Access-Token': token})
        return response.status_code == 200
    except requests.RequestException:
        return False

def shopify_auth_required(func):
    def wrapper(req: HttpRequest):
        logger.info("Incoming headers: %s", req.headers)
        logger.info("Incoming params: %s", req.params)
    
        # Check for internal secret key
        internal_key = req.headers.get('X-Internal-Secret')
        if internal_key == INTERNAL_SECRET_KEY:
            return func(req)

        # Perform Shopify authentication
        domain = req.headers.get('X-Shopify-Domain') or req.params.get('domain')
        token = req.headers.get('X-Shopify-Access-Token') or req.params.get('token')

        if not domain or not token or not verify_shopify_token(domain, token):
            response_content = json.dumps({'error': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'You are not authorized to access this resource.'})
            return HttpResponse(response_content, status_code=401, mimetype="application/json")
        
        return func(req)
    return wrapper

In my frontend web app, I call the request using a ajax call and passing in the necessary headers. This code is below:
  // --- Utility Functions --- //
  const fetchAPI = (url, method, data, successHandler, errorHandler) => {
    $.ajax({
      url,
      method,
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        "X-Shopify-Domain": "{{ shopify_domain }}",
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "{{ shopify_access_token }}"
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      success: successHandler,
      error: errorHandler,
    });
  };

I feel like this is more secure from an API perspective as only the frontend app can successfully call the endpoints.
However, I feel like this opens me up to other issues if anyone is able to get the X-Shopify-Access-Token from the request header.
Is this a suitable solution to adding authentication to my APIs?
I have tried to stay away from having to add another login process for my Shopify app as I am already logged into my Shopify admin portal, and this would require quiet a significate amount of work to implement.

You should make it so you do an AJAX request to your own server which handles the Shopify API call. This will obscure the API Credentials as well as make it so you can do any data manipulation on the backend and have it pristine for when you receive the data back from the server API call.
I don't actually think Shopify will allow you to make the request if you use that method as Shopify knows your credentials would be public. If you are able to make the request like this, you are still partially safe because Shopify blocks requests that aren't coming from your App authorized domains. But this is still fake-able if you're against a good hackerman.
